# Can I pay the fee for several UK visitor visas with one credit card?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, family

I am applying for a UK Standard Visitor visa for myself and family. I understand we have to fill in separate application forms for each family member. Can I pay the visa fee with my credit card for my wife and two minor children?

Comment: Of course you can.  Nobody expects a minor child to pay his or her own visa fee.  By extension it is surely accepted for a single person to pay for all of a family's applications.

Comment: Don't forget to tell your bank that an irregular payment is coming through so they will not block it

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is widely accepted in most visa applications. I do it all the time for my friends when we apply for visa as a group.

Comment: +1 Welcome to TSE!, Nice answer, more answers like that will be welcomed.  Don't forget to upvote the question if you answered it :)